# add object id mongo db php document

Tags: php, mongodb

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5844dd1d3627570f004612a5"),
    "updatedBy" : ObjectId("57c4799d23be243006e188f8"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-12-21T10:08:10.211Z"),
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("5801b7195248ef0e00948934"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-12-05T03:21:01.660Z"),
    "stock" : 50,
    "price" : 15000,
    "owner" : ObjectId("5801b7195248ef0e00948934"),
    "type" : ObjectId("57dce9ad07f96c701c0b24a8"),
    "isValid" : true,
    "grade" : "Grade A",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

i want to ask how to insert **owner** data and also **type** data as ObjectID to mongoDB with php
when i just insert data, it wont changes to object id

anyone?

Comment: You don't insert `ObjectID`. MongoDB creates one when you insert your document. Are you asking how to save docs in php ?

Comment: im sorry before, 
i mean how to insert type or owner data with object id

Comment: Something like `new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId()` for the fields.

Comment: i got MongoId(), 
if i use BSON, it will be BSON ObjectId. Thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer.
just use like this :

> `$id_param = 1270982704y1024kjh12kj4h; new MongoId($id_param)`

thanks a lot your for help